# Is it true that $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(n-1) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {(\Delta t_k^{n})}^2 <M$ for some large M in reals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Is it true that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (n-1) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\Delta t_k^{n})^2 <M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}_+$  if we are partitioning $[0,T]$ for every $n$ and $\Delta t_k^{n}$ is the length of the k'th segment in the nth partition .

Edit : Please note that the mesh size also goes to zero

I have been trying to prove something and if I can show this then my proof would be complete. I suspect that this might not even be true since

$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (n-1) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\Delta t_k^{n})^2 < \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (n-1) \max{\Delta t_k^{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\Delta t_k^{n}) \leq sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T \frac{\max{\Delta t_k^{n}}}{\min{\Delta t_k^{n}}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\Delta t_k^{n})$ and I suspect that the supremum of the ratio and the maximum and minimum is not finite(I reasoned by contradiction without writing a formal proof)

Comment: Could C-S help?

Comment: @martycohen C-S applied to what? Is it even true?

Comment: @martycohen. I tried applyig Cauchy Schwartz to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \Delta t_k^n$ but I dont get anything useful

Answer (score 1):

For any $M>0$ we can find a partition $(x_i)_{0\le i \le n+1}$ of $[0,a]$ such that $n\sum_{k=0}^{n}(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2>M$.

We define $x_k=\frac{ka}{2n}\ \forall k=0,...,n$ and $x_{n+1}=a$ then

$n\sum_{k=0}^{n}(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2=\frac{a^2}{4}+n\frac{a^2}{4}$ which tends to $+\infty$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$ and so we can choose $n$ such that the quantity is greater than $M$.

If we want the mesh of the partition to go to zero then we can instead consider the following partition : $x_i=\frac{i}{n}(a-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}) \ \forall i=0,...,n$ and $x_{n+1}=a$ In this case : 
$n\sum_{k=0}^{n}(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2=(a-\frac {1} {\sqrt[3]{n}})^2 +\sqrt[3]{n}$ which tends to $+\infty$ as well.

Comment: Thank you very much , but I don’t think this reasoning works if the mesh size goes to zero! Would you have a counter example if the mesh size goes to zero

Comment: Indeed what I wrote doesn't work if the mesh tends to zero. I still can't find an answer in this case...

Comment: What about this partition : $x_i=\frac{i}{n}(a-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}) \ \forall i=0,...,n$ and $x_{n+1}=a$ ?

Comment: I dont think it works

Comment: Are you sure ? In this case (If I didn't make any mistakes) the mesh is $max(\frac{1}{n}(T-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}),\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}})$ which goes to 0.and the sum is equal to $(T-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}})^2+\sqrt[3]{n}$ which goes to $+\infty$ Did I overlook something ?